# A table of contents without printing content

Tags: table-of-contents, books, scrbook

I need to print my document without the mainmatter, but the table of contents must contain all titles of chapters and sections and the appendix must have the good number page without the mainmatter pages.

Have you a tip to do that ?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=12,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

%name of toc \addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand*\contentsname{Plan}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\input{tex/titlepage}
\input{tex/introduction}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1} \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter
\input{tex/chapter1}
\input{tex/chapter2} %etc.

    \appendix
\input{tex/appendix1}
\input{tex/appendix2}

    \backmatter
\chapter{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How about compiling fully and setting the page range in the printing dialog?

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and your edition). It doesn't work because I need a correct number for my appendix pages.

Comment: Ah, that's "good number page". It will be hard to achieve this using `\input` as this (in contrast to `\include`) does not write auxiliary files that may help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what "good number page" means. Maybe you are looking for something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=12,oneside]{scrbook}[2017/04/13]% needs at least version 3.23
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}% loads hyperref too

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newif\ifsetmtoc
%\setmtoctrue% uncomment for one run to renew the mtoc file
\newif\ifusemtoc
\usemtoctrue

\newcommand*\printmtoc{}
\xapptocmd\mainmatter
  {%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begingroup\protect\printmtoc}%
    \ifusemtoc
      \begingroup\renewcommand*{\blinddocument}{}% redefine \blinddocument to avoid the output
    \fi
  }{}{\mainmatterPatchFailed}
\xpretocmd\appendix
  {%
    \ifusemtoc\endgroup\fi
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}%
  }{}{\appendixPatchFailed}

\makeatletter
\ifusemtoc
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.mtoc}
    {%
      \renewcommand*\printmtoc{%
        \RedeclareSectionCommands[
          tocpagenumberformat=\@gobble,
          toclinefill=\hfill
        ]{chapter,section}%
        \hypersetup{linktoc=none}%
        \input{\jobname.mtoc}
      }
    }{\setmtoctrue}%
\fi
\ifsetmtoc
  \DeclareNewTOC[
    owner=\jobname
  ]{mtoc}
  \AtBeginDocument{\listoftoc{mtoc}}%
  \xapptocmd\mainmatter
    {\renewcommand*\ext@toc{mtoc}}
    {}{\mainmatterPatchFailed}%
  \xapptocmd\appendix
    {\renewcommand*\ext@toc{toc}}
    {}{\appendixPatchFailed}%
  \usemtocfalse
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Titelpage
\clearpage
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext[3]

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\appendix
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If there are any changes in the mainmatter, either the file with extension `mtoc` have to be removed or there must be one run with `\setmtoctrue` to renew the contents of the `mtoc` file.

If you comment `\usemtoctrue` the content of main matter is printed as usual.

Note that I have used `\blinddocument` instead the `\input` macros in your MWE. Therefore I have redefined `\blinddocument` for the main matter while you have to redefine `\input`.

Comment: Excellent ! When I redefine `\input`, the path of my files stay. Have you a suggestion to hide them ?

Comment: I start to understand a little bit your code. Because it create a .mtoc file, I can comment all of my `\input` until we find a better solution !

Comment: `\renewcommand{\input}[1]{}`?

Comment: Oh, so simple... I realize I should learn more... ;-) Thanks !